# Parsing string in C++ with brackets

Tags: c++

I have to parse string in C++ to get doubles out of it.
String is in format like [(a,b)-(c,d)], where a, b, c and d are going to be double variables.

I was trying to use stringstrem, but it doesn't accept const char argument, so I have no idea right now how to solve it.

My code right now looks like:

```
ss >> "[(" >> a >> "," >> b >> ")-(" >> c >> "," >> d >> ")]";
```

But sadly it doesnt work :(

For example: [(1.2,3.4)-(6.5,7.4)].
And I want:

```
  a=1.2;
  b=3.4;
  c=6.5;
  d=7.4;
```

Comment: Can you have extra space? Do you want to check input string?

Comment: How are the variables declared? How is `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`and `ss` defined and declared?

Comment: You can use a dummy `char dummy;` to write all the unused brackets into. This does however accept any input, not just these specific bracket chars

Comment: Why not try to use regular expression?

Comment: @Andra "Now you've got two problems".

Comment: If you're allowed to use Regex you can do something like this (very naive): https://regex101.com/r/k0pU5r/1

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't want to chceck input string, because it's checked ealier. String is always in this format, but I can do whatever I want with it as long as result is good.

Comment: @KamilCuk I didn't declared it in code, because I wanted code to be clear

Comment: @BasinhetVeld I will check in a sec, but it looks amazing, I always wanted to learn Regrex, but it looks hard and weird :p

Comment: @BasinhetVeld I tried your Regrex, but unfortunetly it doesn't work for string like 
[(11.0,2.132)-(31.12,421.30)], can you tell me how to change it?

Comment: Replace all occurances of `[0-9]` with `\d+`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With input streams, you need to read input to a variable. You could read into a `char` or into a string with `std::istream::read`. Ideally you would check the characters are actually as expected, to catch and probably reject say `__1.2-3.4@#~6.5,7.8++`

```
char chr;
ss >> chr >> chr >> a >> chr >> b >> chr >> chr >> chr >> c >> chr >> d >> chr >> chr;
```

Alternatively you might read it as a string, and then you can use the C++ `<regex>` functionality to match it, perhaps something like:

```
^\[\((\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)\)-\((\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)\)\]$
```

This will give you 4 capture groups on success, which you can then convert to doubles. You can modify this if for example extra spaces are allowed, the decimal point is optional, etc.

If there is any variation in the format at all, for example sometimes you get 3 numbers, e.g. `[(1.2,3.4)-(6.5,7.4)+(1.5,2)]` you would need to do more in depth parsing than the `>>` operator can directly support.

Possibly with logic based on what `ss >> chr` read, or by looping on a regex based on where the previous match ended (instead of matching the entire string at once) although things get a lot more advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this is one of those times when the C library still has the best tool for the job:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string input = "[(1.2,3.4)-(6.5,7.4)]";

    double a, b, c, d;
    if (std::sscanf(input.c_str(), "[(%lf,%lf)-(%lf,%lf)]", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4)
    {
        std::cout << "a=" << a << '\n';
        std::cout << "b=" << b << '\n';
        std::cout << "c=" << c << '\n';
        std::cout << "d=" << d << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Did not parse!\n";
    }
}

// Output:
// 
//   a=1.2
//   b=3.4
//   c=6.5
//   d=7.4
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64fa97db48644855))

IOStreams can do it (as Fire Lancer showed) but *reeeeally* verbosely, and you can roll it yourself (as Ozzy showed) but why go to that effort?

There are also vast *Boost.Spirit* monstrosities that can do it in a "modern" way for very little gain.

Really this is a one-line solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the most elegant way to solve it for sure, but it is a way that humans can read and maintain and possibly extend easily later... I would prefer this over regular expressions :-)

```cpp
        auto input = "[(1.0,2.0)-(3.0,444.555)]";
        std::string in(input);
        for (auto iter = in.begin(); iter < in.end(); iter++)
        {
          char c = *iter;
          // If c == '(' or ',' parse a double number (digits or '.')
          // and save it somewhere. 

          // else: stop parsing a number / continue
        }
```